# How to remove similar words from a list of words?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

```
list1=['Usha', 'Das', 'Anas', 'Chand', 'Tokyo', 'Milkha Singh', 'Gurbachan Singh Randhawa', 'PT Usha', 'KM Beenamol', 'Hima Das', 'under-20', 'Muhammed Anas', 'Dutee Chand', 'the Asian Games', 'Asian Games', 'Olympic Games']
```

From the above list you can see that Das and Hima Das are repeating.I want only full names that is Hima Das. Similarly with Usha and PT Usha.

o/p what I need

```
['Tokyo', 'Milkha Singh', 'Gurbachan Singh Randhawa', 'PT Usha', 'KM Beenamol', 'Hima Das', 'under-20', 'Muhammed Anas', 'Dutee Chand', 'Asian Games', 'Olympic Games']
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a list comprehension + `any`:

```
print([i for i in list1 if not any(i in x and i!=x for x in list1)])
```

Comment: Note that for a large input list, this is much slower than using a set.

Answer (score 2):

Create a set of the individual words from every element in the list with more than one word.

Then use a list-comprehension to filter elements that are entirely in that set.

This solution is `O(n)` which is the best you can do efficiency-wise (better than just checking in the list as that is `O(n^2)`).

```
parts = {w for e in list1 if ' ' in e for w in e.split()}
out = [e for e in list1 if e not in parts]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved a similar problem by using the [Fuzzy Wuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) library. It will return words which are similar to other items in your list based on a number of factors.

```py
all_names=['Usha', 'Das', 'Anas', 'Chand', 'Tokyo', 'Milkha Singh', 'Gurbachan Singh Randhawa', 'PT Usha', 'KM Beenamol', 'Hima Das', 'under-20', 'Muhammed Anas', 'Dutee Chand', 'the Asian Games', 'Asian Games', 'Olympic Games']

for name in list1:
    matches = fuzzy.extractBests(name, list1)
```

From here you can find the longest match in the matches list and treat this as your "candidate" match. e.g "Das" will match "Hima Das" to some degree so they will be returned, and based on length you will choose "Hima Das".

Then add the candidate matches to a set to ensure they are unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=['Usha', 'Das', 'Anas', 'Chand', 'Tokyo', 'Milkha Singh',
     'Gurbachan Singh Randhawa', 'PT Usha', 'KM Beenamol', 'Hima Das', 'under-20', 
      'Muhammed Anas', 'Dutee Chand', 'the Asian Games', 'Asian Games', 'Olympic Games']

 new_list = [value for value in list1 if not any(value in value2 for value2 in list1 if value2 != value)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the for loop:

```
list1=['Usha', 'Das', 'Anas', 'Chand', 'Tokyo', 'Milkha Singh', 'Gurbachan Singh Randhawa', 'PT Usha', 'KM Beenamol', 'Hima Das', 'under-20', 'Muhammed Anas', 'Dutee Chand', 'the Asian Games', 'Asian Games', 'Olympic Games']

uniques = []

for i in list1:
   if i not in uniques:
      uniques.append(i)
print(uniques)
```

Using list comprehension:

```
uniques = [(i for i in list1 if not any(i in x and i!=x for x in list1)]
```